# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - How to open multiple tabs

Tags: perl

I want to open two separate tabs and keep them open in firefox. I am using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. 
Please find the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my @array = <DATA>;

foreach (@array)
{
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(    
                                            activate => 1,  # bring the tab to the foreground
                                            autoclose => 0  # to prevent autoclosing of the Tab
                                        ); 
    $mech->get($_);
}

__DATA__
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
```

Above code works fine and creates two tabs. But I am not happy with my approach as I am creating two object. I am looking for some way to open multiple tabs. I could not do it with a single `$mech` object and hence created multiple object using for loop.

I have gone through below documentation:

[WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm)

[Firefox::Application](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/Firefox/Application.pm)

[WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::Display](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/WWW-Mechanize-Plugin-Display-1.01/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/Display.pm)

[WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Cookbook.pod)

however none of them seem to answer this issue. OR I may have missed some information in those documentation.

**QUESTION:**

1. Is it possible to open multiple tabs using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`
   or some other relevant firefox mechanize module? and how?
2. Personally, I did not like my code pasted above whihc is creating
   multiple objects. Is it OK/BAD to create multiple objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with creating multiple objects.  You may be concerned by the memory overhead.  The objects may have extra stuff going on (localhost TCP sockets in this case) that you'd rather not duplicate.  You may find it irritating to have to loop over your multiple objects every time you want to perform one logical action that must be shared across the objects.

But nobody's going to recoil in horror.  "Multiple objects?!  HOW DARE YOU."

If all that you want to do is open multiple tabs, I use something like this:

```
sub browse {
  my $method = $_[1] ? 'new-window' : 'new-tab';
  system firefox => -remote => "openURL($_[0],$method)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I am not able to understand your code. Could you please elaborate it little further? Does your code make use any of the mechanize methods? OR is it just a pseudo code ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Er, what? It's plain Perl. It defines a subroutine, accesses arguments, defines a lexical variable, selects a value with the ternary operator, invokes n-ary (safe) `system` with three scalar arguments - two of them fat-comma'd barewords, the last a string literal with two interpolated variables. Any Perl tutorial should cover this.

Comment: I guess I  should have been more precise. Anyway. What you said makes more sense after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options . I was thinking with respect to the mechanize stuff where as your code runs the firfox binary CLI and hence I was not abel to co-relate the two. thanks for your time.