# Getting page source from all pages at same time using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello Everyone,
          I have some 30 pages of epaper document (Eg:-http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/index.aspx?eid=31806&dt=20160301) How can i get pagesource using selenium webdriver for all the pages at same time

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Would you try to open multi-tabs simultaneously using selenium in firefox/chrome?
See more at: [Controlling firefox tabs in selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079411/controlling-firefox-tabs-in-selenium) [Opening a new tab in the same window session of the browser through selenium web driver command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165193/opening-a-new-tab-in-the-same-window-session-of-the-browser-through-selenium-web) if selenium not support, try mechanize [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486350/wwwmechanizefirefox-how-to-open-multiple-tabs?s=1|2.2483](http://stackoverfl

Comment: Thank you for responding...No i dont want to open multiple tabs, i just want to open a single tab and get pagesource of all 30 pages